# Oauth refresh token provider error in ValidateClientAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, token

I apologize for my English. I presented the following problem. I'm working with C # asp.net MVC 5.

I am implementing a server with the OAuth 2 bearer token and token refresh. When requesting the access token returns me refresh token and token with client_credential grant_type, client_id and client_secret. The problem is to apply the new refresh token from token. When I shipping grant_type refresh_token and refresh_token parameter as the first method is called ValidateClientAuthentication. but as shipping and client_secret client_id not validate me because I check the existence of an object in the database by these parameters. What am I doing wrong. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move th secret validation to GrantClientCredentials method and it´s work. Thanks for all

Comment: How do you retrieve secret in GrantClientCredentials ?

Comment: In ValidateClientAuthentication i set a temporary var to context like this context.OwinContext.Set("oauth:clientSecret", clientSecret); then in GrantClientCredential method i access to this temporary var in this way var clientSecret = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("oauth:clientSecret");